# How can I improve performance in my SpriteKit game while displaying adMob banner ads?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob

I recently developed a game in Swift using SpriteKit. The game runs perfectly well without any ads, however, after inserting banner ads on the bottom using Google's adMob I noticed a significant drop in frame rate and performance during gameplay. Here is how I incorporated them into my game.

```
// in the viewDidLoad()
        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-2217093431614134/7329876635"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())

        bannerView.delegate = self

        addBannerViewToView(bannerView)

// function to add Banner ad to view
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        view.addConstraints(
        [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                           attribute: .centerX,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: view,
                           attribute: .centerX,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 0)
        ])
    }
```

For now I disabled banner ads during the actual game. They appear again when there's no gameplay taking place. This is a temporal solution. Is there an actual solution to show banner ads during gameplay while not affecting the game's performance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much memory does the app consumes with an ad?  And how large is an ad?

Comment: I am displaying ads in my game and the fps doesn't drop. Make sure you optimise your game as much as you can, so when ads slow your app, user won't notice. Use multi-threading.

Comment: You need to do this on a background queue, creating the ad is a little heavy and requires a few frames to complete.